# How to build reputation back

Tags: management, manager, politics, offices

I am currently working as an intern, and was allocated to work on a big project. I was enjoying the work.

We interns have to report to senior most managers as to what we are working on with mentors. I spoke with my manager he mentioned not to disclose the work.

I made a presentation keeping it very generic for that topic, but I didn’t show to my manager, and on the day of presentation he was very mad at me and also accused me of showing someone’s else work. I was soon asked to leave the project and had a discussion with my manager.

How do I navigate this situation. Recently he gave me very poor performance feedback as well even though I worked under him for just 1 month.

Currently I am under different manager and allocated to different department. But I feel this has created a bad reputation of me in the office and my current manager is also a good friend of my previous manager. They must have known about the mishap I committed due to miscommunication. How can I build my reputation back again?

Comment: You have to inform senior management of your progress and your current line manager is preventing you from disclosing to upper management? Can you clarify the apparent conflict in your second paragraph? Is line management  aligned with senior management?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I build my reputation back again.

Don't screw up again. This was your biggest error:

> I didn’t show [the presentation] to my manager

Your manager had made it very clear to you they were concerned about the content of the presentation; by not getting your manager's sign off as to the content, you set yourself up to fail.

Comment: That's unfortunately not a question we can answer; if you are struggling mentally, I'd strongly encourage you to talk to a health professional.

Answer (score 2):

Best way of dealing with a mistake

1. Fess up: admit it openly, apologize and take full responsibility
2. Damage control: fix what can still be fixed, save what can still be saved even if it's extra work for you.
3. Analyze what happens. What went wrong and what could have been differently to avoid this ?
4. Create corrective actions. DO something that will make sure that you'll never make the same mistake again. Or even better: no one else makes the mistake again either.
5. Let the people affected by the error know what you are doing and ask for their feedback.
6. Then move on. What's done is done.

Everyone makes mistakes, it's a fact of life. What matters is how you deal with it. Mistakes are painful but are also often significant learning and growth opportunities.